# Google Places iOS SDK: How to Get Point of Interest Based on Text Search

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places-api

If you go to google.com and search "Attractions in London", in the result page on the first line you will see a list of Point of Interest (POI) with its name, photo, and description.

I want to get this list of POI on my iOS app, without having the user typing "Attractions in London"; I will pre-load this list as suggested places in London. I've read through the Google Places API for IOS here: https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start. But I could not find any sample to search by text.

The only way I found is by accessing the Google Place Web Service API here: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search and do the text search. Get the JSON result and map it to my custom google place object.

Does anybody has experience doing this using client-site API iOS SDK? Not sure if I missed anything in their guide, or it's not documented or Web Service API the only way..

Thanks in advance!